# vs c# - problems with attached file in outlook

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I´m having a problem with attaching files into outlook.

I´ve this code, where I´m viable to attach a file and then send it using my outlook (without credential, just using my profile credentials in windows)

```
private void tsbOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
  Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem)(oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
  ((Outlook.MailItem)email).Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
  ((Outlook.MailItem)email).To = "myemail@maydomain.com";
  //((Outlook.MailItem)email).CC = "myemail@maydomain.com";  
  ((Outlook.MailItem)email).Subject = lblUser.Text + " - " + lblDepartment.Text;
  **((Outlook.MailItem)email).Attachments.Add(lblAdd.Text.ToString(), Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); **
  ((Outlook.MailItem)email).Body = lblFail.Text + "\n" + "\n" + lblDescription.Text + "\n" + "\n" + lblComment.Text;
  ((Outlook.MailItem)email).Send();
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Su solicitud ha sido enviada." + "\n" + "Gracias por contactar ServiceDesk BA.");
    Close();
  }
}
```

I use this part for file, lblAdd.text is where I take the path of the file:

**((Outlook.MailItem)email).Attachments.Add(lblAdd.Text.ToString(), Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);**

the problem is when this path is empty, I´m not viable to sent email without an attached file since I change this part of the code.
How can I add an "exeption" for this???

Many thanks in advance for your help.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find out if the file exists?

Use :

```
// set up email

if(File.Exists(lblAdd.Text))
{
  // add attachment
  email.Attachments.Add(...);
}

// send
```

Comment: something like that.
in case that there is no file, just send emails without attached.

Comment: i was trying to use something like

NotImplementedException();

Comment: I don´t have any definition for File, so I´m not viable to use File.Exists.